# What species is this cocoon?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

I found this cocoon outside my house and I want to know what insect might be inside it and it’s species. Please help!

I found it a day ago when it was a worm, now its a cocoon, it’s like outside the main entrance (which is like 2 metres high) and the cocoon was half way on the left, and it was out in the sun, to be honest I’m surprised little kids didn’t kill it yet.
I live in Kuwait in a town called Hadiya.

I don’t see many worms in Kuwait, I’ve only seen like 4 in my whole life.

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site!  In order to be able to identify it, we'll probably need more information - where do you live?  You found it recently, I presume?  Also, a more precise description of the environment in which you found it could be helpful: "outside my house" leaves a lot of unanswered questions: how high? it looks like a painted surface?  Is it in the shade or in full sun?  Please [edit] to include more detail.  Thanks!